# Azure: Deploy from source control using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

How do I deploy a particular branch (i.e. development branch) using Visual Studio Team Services Git repository in Azure. When I deploy from a Bitbucket repository it asks me which branch to deploy from. It does no such thing with the Team Services repo.

Once my website is linked to my Visual Studio Team Services git repository, the Deployments section in Azure reads:

> The team project is linked.
>
> > Visual Studio Team Services will build and deploy your project to Windows Azure on your next check-in.

How do I deploy from my development branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the build definition with Visual Studio: Go to the Team Explorer toolbox, Navigate to the "Build" section, find the Build Definition automatically created by Windows Azure, edit the definition, Go to the "Process" section, Find the path of the solution to build and replace it with the path of the sln file inside your branch.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your answer almost solved the problem. Instead of the "Process" section, I went to the "Source Settings" section where I was able to monitor the develop branch.